# Using Skulpt with React

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, skulpt

I'm interested in creating a React web app that teaches kids how to use Python through programs such as Turtle graphics. I thought that [Skulpt](http://skulpt.org/) would be a good library to use since it already has a demo that shows [here](https://skulpt.org/using.html#html) how to use it within a HTML page. However, while it loads fine in a normal web page, I'm having difficulty getting it to run in my React app, probably due to the global variables that skulpt.min.js sets. Specifically, I get the following message:

```
./src/utils/skulpt-stdlib.js
Line 1:1:  'Sk' is not defined  no-undef
```

I imagine it's because the skulpt-stdlib.js script relies on the skulpt.min.js script to be read first and set its global variables before the skulpt-stdlib.js script works. What would I need to do in React to get this to work the same way it does in a normal web page? Thank you!

Comment: would be interested on same

Comment: I would be interested too

Comment: I would be interested as well

Answer (score 1):

try this, hope this works, i am also trying, i will update this if it works completely.

> add the below code in the beginning of skulpt.min.js

```
function Sk() {}
```

> and the below code in the end of skulpt.min.js

```
export { Sk };
```